# CSVFormat add quotation to header

Tags: java, apache-commons-csv

I am using apache.commons.csv to create a CSV file. When generating the file ,I want to parse a header with the method `.withHeader()`. The values I parse should have quotes like "FILENAME". To do that I want to use an enum class. However I am not quite sure how it works to add quotes around the name. I tested it and with that code:

```java
    private enum Header{
        FILENAME("\"FILENAME\""), 
        TEST("\"Test\"");
    
        private final String string;
    
        Header(String string){
            this.string = string;
        }
    }

    public void addHeader(File outFile) throws IOException{
            CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(outFile, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(Header.class));
    }
```

However when `outfile` is created it only contains the header without quotes. Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? I know I use a string array as header but I would like to avoid that, because I have a lot of values an the string would get quite long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by George Nechifor, we can use [`CSVFormat#withHeader(String...)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withHeader-java.lang.String...-) for better flexibility. To avoid duplication and hardcoding, of course we should use the value from enum, with a simple mapping.

```
Arrays.stream(Header.values()).map(Header::getCsvHeader).toArray(String[]::new)
```

And will result in
`"""FILENAME""","""Test"""`
An runnable example is as follows(with apache commons-csv 1.8):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CsvWithEnumHeader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        addHeader(new File("C://temp/demo.csv"));
    }

    public static void addHeader(File outFile) throws IOException {
        // apache common csv 1.8 cannot compile with new CSVPrinter(outFile,...)
        try (CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(new FileWriter(outFile),
                CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(Arrays.stream(Header.values()).map(Header::getCsvHeader).toArray(String[]::new)))) {
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public enum Header {
    FILENAME("\"FILENAME\""),
    TEST("\"Test\"");

    private final String csvHeader;

    Header(String csvHeader) {
        this.csvHeader = csvHeader;
    }

    public String getCsvHeader() {
        return csvHeader;
    }
}
```

### Update from the comment

it seems what OP want is the header get quoted instead of header containing double quote. We may use `withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL)` and remove `\"` in `getCsvHeader`.

```java
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL).withHeader(Arrays.stream(Header.values()).map(Header::getCsvHeader).toArray(String[]::new)))
```

The result will be
`"FILENAME","Test"`
Please note that this will also quote the record in csv. If we only want to quote the header, please refer to [CSVPrinter remove quotes only from header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902352/csvprinter-remove-quotes-only-from-header), which is doing in reverse way, but the tricks still apply.

---

Comment: Ok thanks that solved almost my solution only thing is that my output hast three " instead of one.

Comment: @user15980267, I edited the answer to address your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how `withHeader(Header.class)` is implemented, it uses the Enums's `.name()` method to get the enum value as a string, which gets the actual enum value as string: `FILENAME` not `"\"FILENAME\""`.
To get the double quotes in the csv you could use a String array like this:

```java
CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(new FileWriter(outFile), CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("\"FILENAME\"", "\"TEST\""));
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer I wanted to avoid this solution but if it's not possible with the enum I have to deal with it.